# Nvidia graphics card and Intel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z510, I5-4200M and GT 740M. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My laptop freezes after suspend. I think the problem is in hybrid graphics, turning off GT 740M helps. Nvidia prime doesn't help. Is there any way to make my graphics work the right way?

Comment: What Nvidia drivers are you using?

Comment: Nvidia binary driver - version 361.42 from Nvidia-361(proprietary, tested).

Answer (score 0):

It happens because ubuntu is not detecting your nvidia graphics card.
To solve this

1. Go to Addition Drivers in ubuntu from the Menu.
2. Go to Additional Drivers Tab.
3. Select "using NVIDIA binary driver". And then Apply.
4. Restart Your Computer.

If its still not fixed try using "NVIDIA legacy driver".

Incase you have just installed ubuntu,no additional driver will be displayed. Wait till ubuntu detects all the additional drivers.

Comment: It still does not work. There's no legacy driver option.

Comment: I downloaded the driver available only with the developer check box checked and rebooted. When I open the lid after suspend, I see this: [ 149.692212] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:07:00): 79, GPU has fallen off the bus.

Comment: When I use the open source driver, there's no problem with suspend, but the card doesn't work either. Using all nvidia drivers, the card works, but there's suspend problems.